# Verify LavinMQ Version

Tags: message-queue, amqp, lavinmq

I've been exploring the AMQP message broker, [LavinMQ](https://lavinmq.com/) a lot lately.

I'm currently trying to figure out what version of the broker is running on my server.

Is there a CLI command for this? Maybe something similar to RabbitMQ's `rabbitmqctl status` command.

Answer (score 1):

LavinMQ has its own command line interface, lavinmqctl. Read more on how to use it [here](https://lavinmq.com/documentation/lavinmqctl).

To check the lavinmq version on a server use the command: `lavinmqctl -v`